# How to extract data in HTML table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How can I extract a particular data (ie, 39.74% in this case) followed by "Proj. EPS Growth (F1)" in the following HTML example with BeautifulSoup?  I'm completely new to Python.  Thank you!

```
<div class="high_low_table" id="high_low_table">
</table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (Q1) </th>
<td>19.56%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (F1) </th>
<td>39.74%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
data = soup.find('div', class_="high_low_table").text
```

Comment: you want only one output or both output in table as output??

Comment: Line 2 should be ```<table>``` and not ```</table>```.  See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: I want only one output.

Comment: Is this always the last row? Or are you identifying it by the nearest `<th>` text?

Comment: It would be better if you share the URL.

Comment: It's not always in the last row. I can identify it by the header text.  But I don't know how to do it.  My actual target HTML (also private account) has much more data.  This is a simple example for me to learn and expand from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you have two th elements with identical attributes. Therefore you need to inspect the text part of those elements to identify the one you're interested in. Try this:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

HTML = '''
<html>
<div class="high_low_table" id="high_low_table">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (Q1) </th>
<td>19.56%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (F1) </th>
<td>39.74%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
'''

soup = BS(HTML, 'html.parser')
for th in soup.find_all('th', attrs={'class': 'alpha', 'scope': 'row'}):
    if 'Proj. EPS Growth (F1)' in th.text:
        print(th.find_next('td').text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken your data as HTML:

```
html="""<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (Q1) </th>
<td>19.56%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (F1) </th>
<td>39.74%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

we can use `re` module to find specific data by passing `text` in `find` method

```
import re
data=soup.find("th",class_="alpha",text=re.compile("F1"))
```

after finding specigfic tag you can find `td` using `find_next()` method

```
prj=data.get_text(strip=True)
value=data.find_next("td").get_text()

print(prj,value,sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
Proj. EPS Growth (F1)
39.74%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it for the given HTML Code.

- Select the second row `<tr>` (*because that is where the data you need is present*) that is inside a `div` with `id='high_low_table'`.

  ```
  trs = soup.find('div', attrs= {'id': 'high_low_table'}).find_all('tr')[1]
  ```
- Prints the text present inside the `<td>` tags. *i.e, 39.74%*

  ```
  print(trs.find('td').text)
  ```
- Prints the text present inside `<th>`. *i.e. Proj. EPS Growth (F1)*

  ```
  print(trs.find('th').text)
  ```

Here is the Complete Code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<div class="high_low_table" id="high_low_table">
</table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (Q1) </th>
<td>19.56%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="alpha" scope="row">Proj. EPS Growth (F1) </th>
<td>39.74%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
trs = soup.find('div', attrs= {'id': 'high_low_table'}).find_all('tr')[1]
print(trs.find('td').text)
print(trs.find('th').text)
```

```
39.74%
Proj. EPS Growth (F1)
```